# GLEW library not linking in CodeBlocks (MinGW)

Tags: windows, opengl, codeblocks, glew, freeglut

The undefined references that it lists are clearly set up in 'glew.h.' I have included the libraries in the linker, the includes in the search directories, and have copied the glew32.dll into the system registry (as well as a bunch of other places - several spots inside MinGW's directory as well as the debug directory). I am using the most recent version of GLEW on their website, though codeBlocks and freeGlut were downloaded back in October/November. I'm attempting to follow the swiftless tutorial on OpenGL/Glut.

Clearly, the debugger is not linking the libraries/header correctly, but I can't figure out why - I've searched everywhere, and there's some things about making minGW static that I don't quite understand, but it sounds like it doesn't need to be done in order for it to work.

Error pasta:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Window Tutorial (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\glew-1.10.0\include\GL 
-LC:\freeglut\include\GL 
-LC:\freeglut\lib 
-LC:\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32  
-o "bin\Debug\Window Tutorial.exe" 
obj\Debug\main.o            
C:\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32\glew32.lib 
C:\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32\glew32s.lib      
C:\freeglut\lib\glut32.lib 
C:\freeglut\lib\libfreeglut.a      
C:\freeglut\lib\libfreeglut_static.a 


obj\Debug\main.o: In function `display':
C:/Users/CNOVDM/Other/codeBlocks/Swiftless/Window/Window Tutorial/main.c:5: undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
C:/Users/CNOVDM/Other/codeBlocks/Swiftless/Window/Window Tutorial/main.c:6: undefined   reference to `glClear@4'
C:/Users/CNOVDM/Other/codeBlocks/Swiftless/Window/Window Tutorial/main.c:7: undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity@0'
C:/Users/CNOVDM/Other/codeBlocks/Swiftless/Window/Window Tutorial/main.c:9: undefined reference to `glFlush@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 4 seconds)
4 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 4 seconds)
```

The code:

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glut.h>

void display (void) {
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //Clear the background of our window to red
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colour buffer (more buffers later on)
glLoadIdentity(); // Load the Identity Matrix to reset our drawing locations

glFlush(); // Flush the OpenGL buffers to the window
}
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT
glewInit();
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE); //Set Up a basic Display Buffer (only single buffered for now)
glutInitWindowSize(500,500);    // Set the width and height of the window
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100); // set the position of the window
glutCreateWindow("My First OpenGL Window"); // Set the title for the window

glutDisplayFunc(display); // Tell GLUT to use the method "display" for rendering

glutMainLoop(); // Enter GLUT's main loop
}
```

Comment: **1.** How do you copy a DLL into the system registry? If you mean you copied it into `Windows\System32` or `Windows\SysWOW64` then don't do that. **2.** These have nothing to do with GLEW, you forgot to link to `opengl32.lib`.

Comment: You would be correct. The tutorial I was following was used for Visual Studio - and I guess that's already linked by default as it is never mentioned. Thanks for helping out with such a stupid mistake.
http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/window.html

Oh, and yes, I meant I put it into the system folder. I don't have a 64-bit OS - so it was just System32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to link to the lib files.

read the [manual 1.11.13](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html).

If you use x64 system, you should put the `glew32.dll` in `lib\release\x64` to `System32`, and  the other on in `lib\release\Win32` to `SysWOW64`

this [link](http://www.sepago.de/e/helge/2008/04/02/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-6) will help you to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you still need to link with GL even if you link with glew. try adding -lopengl32